# Access web UI on a remote Linux server without using SSH

Tags: linux, user-interface, unix, web, networking

Assume that you run an application with a web UI (e.g. Jupyter, Kubernetes Dashboard UI) on a Linux/UNIX server (sarah@10.0.0.100). On the server, you confirm that you can access the web UI by opening http:/ /localhost:8001 on Firefox.

You have separate workstations in the same network. Is there any easy way to access the web UI by simply opening http:/ /10.0.0.100:8001 from a web browser on the workstations?

---

*Workaround.* Establish an SSH connection with port tunneling:

```
$ ssh -N -L 8001:localhost:8001 sarah@10.0.0.100
```

You can establish a similar connection by using other SSH client tools such as PuTTY. Open http:/ /localhost:8001 from a web browser on your workstation.

But it is tedious to establish an SSH connection every time so that I need a better idea.

Comment: Yes, and if nothing blocks the port, it should work right away.  On the server, make sure nothing is blocking port 8001 (firewall, iptables, SELinux, ...).  Then the browser on the client system will be ok to access it with `http://IP-ADDRESS:8001/

Comment: In that case, is there any way to alter the port at the Linux server end? Say, making all incoming and outgoing traffic with port 8001 moves to port 8080 (HTTPS) on the server. Assume that the clients (laptop workstations) have access to 10.0.0.100:8080.

Answer (score 1):

why not just do this?

```
jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8001
```

Comment: Please reread the original question: it is about a UNIX(-like) operating system level, not about a specific application. Obviously, your command doesn't work with Kubernetes Dashboard UI and many other applications with web UIs.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you want a system-level proxy that works on your local lan, you can do the following:

1. on your workstation, install [proxychains-ng](https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng)
2. modify proxychains.conf with the following:

```
[ProxyList]
socks4  127.0.0.1 8001
```

3. on your workstation run:

```
proxychains4 -f proxychains.conf ssh -L 8001:0.0.0.0:8001 sarah@10.0.0.100
```

Now you can hit `http://<your_workstation>:8001` from anywhere on your LAN and it will be proxied to your remote system.

To keep your tunnel always connected, you can install `autossh`, and replace the proxy command with:

```
proxychains4 -f proxychains.conf \
    autossh -t -M 0 
        -o 'ServerAliveInterval=30' \
        -o 'ServerAliveCountMax=10000' \
        -o 'SendEnv=TERM_PROGRAM' \
        -o 'ExitOnForwardFailure=no' \
        -o 'TCPKeepAlive=yes' \
        -L 8001:0.0.0.0:8001 \
        sarah@10.0.0.100
```

You should also consider you using key-based auth for this.

Comment: Are you sure about running proxychains4 **on the workstation (client laptop)** instead of on the server that hosts web UI apps? I did it on the server and got the error: `[proxychains] Strict chain  ...  127.0.0.1:8001  ...  timeout`.

Comment: I ran this on on my macbook with a Linux sever on the other side.  It works.  You may need to start your Jupyter server explicitly pinned to the port and exposed on all interfaces, because that's what I did.

Comment: SSH tunneling seems easier then; it only uses an SSH client.